# How to override or stop an .on() function when it meets the condition of another .on() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll, jquery-events

I have body and footer content with an arrow that continuously shows after a little delay until it reaches the bottom of the page. What I'm trying to achieve is basically hide the arrow when the footer is visible and resume showing the arrow when the footer is not visible. The problem with this is I tried to override it by adding several different code options in the on('inview') function to hide the arrow but it doesn't work and continues executing the other function.

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/39x76r9x/

**on('.inview') function:**

```
// WHEN FOOTER COMES IN VIEW HIDE ARROW
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('footer').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
          if (isInView) {
            // element is now visible in the viewport
              $('.bounce').hide();
              //$('.bounce').css('display','none');
              //$(".bounce").css("cssText", "display: none !important;");
              $('.bounce').attr("style", "display: none !important");
              console.log('element visible');
              $('#text-status').text("Footer Visible");
          } else {
            // element has gone out of viewport
              $('.bounce').show();
              console.log('element not visible');
              $('#text-status').text("Footer Not Visible");
          }
        });
  });
```

**on('scroll') function:**

```
var scrollPos;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

    $('.bounce').hide(); // hide the bouncing arrow
    scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // gets the vertical scroll position

    // check if scrollbar has reach end of page
    if(scrollPos == ($(document).height() - $(window).height()))
    {
        $('.bounce').hide();
    }
    else if(scrollPos == 0) // scrollbar at top of page
    {
        $('.bounce').delay(800).fadeIn(300);
    }

});

// jquery.unevent plugin - when an event hasn't been fired for a specified time (# in milliseconds at end of this function), this event will trigger
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $('.bounce').fadeIn(300);

    if(scrollPos == ($(document).height() - $(window).height()))
    {
        $('.bounce').hide();
    }
}, 800);
```

Comment: If you want to hide the arrow when footer is in the view, that could be done by simply removing code from line 9 to 34 on your jsfiddle, here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/08x4kovk/1/

Comment: @azs06 But this is removing the delay feature of the arrow which I don't want. I want to keep those functions there and cease those functions (hide the arrow) when the footer is visible.

Comment: sorry, I think I am not understanding the issue you are having, do you want to hide arrow after some time passed, because on your scroll event function you hiding it immediately, ` $('.bounce').hide()`

Comment: No, i want it to work like this. When page loads, the arrows shows. Anytime the user scroll, the arrow disappears, if it hasn't reached the footer, there's a 1-second delay before the arrow reappears. It'll keep doing that wherever I am positioned in the page which it already does. Now, when I reach the footer, it will hide the arrow permanently as long as the footer is in view of the page (which is not working). If I scroll back up with the footer being out of view, it will resume its functionality of showing/delaying again as mentioned above. I hope it's a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create flag like `footerIsVisible` and set it to `false`, and set it `true` only when it's in view.And use it in jQuery `unevent` to show arrow icon. Here is a working example, of what I think you are trying to achieve. I removed some codes which I felt redundant.

```js
var footerIsVisible = false;
var scrollPos;
    
$(window).on('scroll', function(){      
    $('.bounce').hide(); 
    scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();        
    if(scrollPos == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
        $('.bounce').hide();
    }
        
});
    
// jquery.unevent plugin - when an event hasn't been fired for a specified time (# in milliseconds at end of this function), this event will trigger
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if(!footerIsVisible){
     $('.bounce').fadeIn(300);      
    }     
}, 800);
// WHEN FOOTER COMES IN VIEW HIDE ARROW
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('footer').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
          if (isInView) {
              footerIsVisible = true;
              $('#text-status').text("Footer Visible");
          } else {
            footerIsVisible = false;
              $('#text-status').text("Footer Not Visible");
          }
        });
  });
```

```css
.fa {
 width: 50px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font: normal 85px 'FontAwesome';
 line-height: 105px;
 text-rendering: auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.fa-angle-double-down:before {content: "⍗";}
.bounce {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 30px;
 left: 50% ;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-left: -30px;
    bottom: 3%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -ms-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 animation: bounce 2s infinite;
 -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
 -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
 -o-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
 0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
 40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
 60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
 0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateY(0);}
 40% {-moz-transform: translateY(-30px);}
 60% {-moz-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
@-o-keyframes bounce {
 0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-o-transform: translateY(0);}
 40% {-o-transform: translateY(-30px);}
 60% {-o-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
@keyframes bounce {
 0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
 50% {transform: translateY(-30px);}
 50% {transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="text-status" style="position:fixed;right:10px;font-size:40px;">Footer Not Visible</div>
<div class="bounce">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
</div>
<div style="height:1000px;background:red;">
  body content
</div>
<footer style="height:100px;background:green;">
  footer content
</footer>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mmmeff/jquery.inview2/master/jquery.inview2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/yckart/jquery.unevent.js/master/jquery.unevent.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of that code https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/1un4dc11/1/

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.